# ActiveMQ message selector

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

In my message queue contains several messages. This I want to group by specific properties. These all have a custom property "item-id"

This I would now certain values to: sports, movie ...

I do this like:

```
new MessageCreator() {
 ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
 message.setObject(data);
 message.setStringProperty("item-id", "sports");
}
```

This value is also displayed in the Queue at the Properties.

When I try to retrieve the messages which contain this property I get no result.

First trial:

```
 Connection con = pc.createConnection();
 Session sess =con.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);       
 AmqMessagesQueryFilter queryFilter = new AmqMessagesQueryFilter(pc, queue); 
 con.start();
 String selector = "item-id = 'sports'";
 List messages = queryFilter.query(selector);
```

But the list is empty

Second trial:

```
 Connection con = pc.createConnection();
 Session sess = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

 AmqMessagesQueryFilter queryFilter = new AmqMessagesQueryFilter(pc, queue);

 QueueBrowser queueBrowser = sess.createBrowser(queue,"item-id = 'sports'");
 con.start();
 List messages=Collections.list(queueBrowser.getEnumeration());
```

Also the list is empty.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you put some messages in the queue before running your query filter ?

Comment: yes and no. I tried with  some messages in the queue before start and with an empty queue on start.

Comment: Disconnect all listeners, Put some messages in the queue that have an header 'item-id' and value 'sports' and then run your filter again.

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is too late, but this will probably save someone a lot of hours wasted (and frustration).

Do not use dashes in your message selector. Use underscores if needed.
Lookup "Identifiers" here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Hyphens in filter expression properties prevent all messages from being delivered to the subscribing client; "hyphenated_props:" prefix overcomes that.

Expanding on the above, selector properties need to comply to JMS rules, which forbid hyphens / dashes.

From the [ActiveMQ Artemis Documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.5.0/book.pdf):

> The JMS spec also states that property identifiers (and therefore the identifiers which are valid for use in a filter expression) are an, "unlimited-length sequence of letters and digits, the first of which must be a letter. A letter is any character for which the method Character.isJavaLetter returns true . This includes _ and $ . A letter or digit is any character for which the method Character.isJavaLetterOrDigit returns true.
> This constraint means that hyphens (i.e. - ) cannot be used. However, this constraint can be overcome by using the hyphenated_props: prefix. For example, if a message had the foo-bar property set to 0 then the filter expression hyphenated_props:foo-bar = 0 would match it."

More discussion on the topic here:  [Message Selectors in JMS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=messages-message-selectors-in-jms)

While the discussion is in the Artemis context, the same restrictions are seen to apply in practice to recent versions of ActiveMQ Classic as well (tested on v5.18.2 and 6.0.1 - Stomp only). Clients that add a selector that contains hyphenated properties don't receive any messages, even if the content itself would have resulted in a match.